# Symfony 4 : Delete all cache items which begin with something

Tags: symfony, caching, symfony4

In Symfony 4, I constructed cache elements dynamically:

```
$cache = new FilesystemAdapter();
$article = $cache->get('article_' . $code, function (ItemInterface $item) use ($code) {
     $item->expiresAfter(864000);

     return $this->getArticle($code);
});
```

I want on certain actions to be able to delete all cache items which begin with `"article_"`. Is that possible or do I have to know all the codes I used to delete those cache items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tag all your items and then delete all the items refered by the tag :

https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-tagged-cache

Comment: Thanks ! That need tagAwareAdapter. There's more info here : https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/components/cache/cache_invalidation.html](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/components/cache/cache_invalidation.html)

Comment: Don't forget to tag your question as answered. That will help others.